# Firebase Table Not Created

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I want to create a firebase table Along with name Users along with the attributes Name, Email, Password and by default Id and also register with firebase authentication. But when I run the application It shows the null Data.

The Data Shown in Firebase is
[image: Data Created in Firebase]

Here is my code of SignUp Authentication and Saving the User Attributes in the Database.
This Activity is all about Saving the User Attributes as well as create a new user with email.

```
TextView TxtName,TxtEmail,TxtPassword;
Button BTNFB,BTNEMAIL;
FirebaseAuth mAuth;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
DatabaseReference databaseNameRegistration;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
    TxtName= findViewById(R.id.txtname);
    TxtEmail= findViewById(R.id.txtemail);
    BTNEMAIL= findViewById(R.id.btnregisteremail);
    TxtPassword= findViewById(R.id.txtpassword);
    progressDialog= new ProgressDialog(this);
    mAuth= FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    databaseNameRegistration= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Child Safety");
    BTNEMAIL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FunRegisterUser();
        }
    });
}
private void FunRegisterUser() {
    final String email = TxtEmail.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
    final String password = TxtPassword.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
    final String name= TxtName.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)|| !android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()){
        TxtEmail.setError("Please Enter a Valid Email");
        return;
    }
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)|| password.length() < 4 || password.length() > 10){
        TxtPassword.setError("Enter The Password");
        return;
    }
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(name))
    {
        TxtName.setError("Please Enter a Valid Email");
        return;
    }
    progressDialog.setMessage("Registering User...");
    progressDialog.show();
    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                    String id = databaseNameRegistration.push().getKey();
                    ClassUsersDetail classUsersDetail= new ClassUsersDetail(id,name,email,password);
                    databaseNameRegistration.child(id).setValue(classUsersDetail);
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Registered Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Not Registered...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
}
```

Here is Class for the Activity to get and set the data

```
public class ClassUsersDetail {
    String TxtName;
    String TxtEmail;
    String TxtPassword;
    String UserId;

    public ClassUsersDetail(){
    }

    public ClassUsersDetail(String txtName, String txtEmail, String txtPassword, String userId) {
        TxtName = txtName;
        TxtEmail = txtEmail;
        TxtPassword = txtPassword;
        UserId = userId;
    }

    public String getTxtName() {
        return TxtName;
    }

    public String getTxtEmail() {
        return TxtEmail;
    }

    public String getTxtPassword() {
        return TxtPassword;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return UserId;
    }

    public void setTxtName(String txtName) {
        TxtName = txtName;
    }

    public void setTxtEmail(String txtEmail) {
        TxtEmail = txtEmail;
    }

    public void setTxtPassword(String txtPassword) {
        TxtPassword = txtPassword;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        UserId = userId;
    }
}
```

What I want to do is save a user with his name, email and password in the Database.

Comment: `setValue` has a second argument that takes a `DatabaseReference.CompletionListener`. Add the listener, try to submit your data again and post any error message you receive up here.

Comment: Where to add this listener?

Comment: You pass it in as the second argument of `.setValue(classUserDetails)`. See the docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.html#setValue(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object,%20com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.CompletionListener)).

Comment: I am unable to understand the .setValue, Can You Answer the Question In order to Help me to understand in a better Format to resolve my problem

Comment: Are getting this message `"Not Registered..."`?